# Statistical test for comparing CPU speed between two models

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I've been working on two simulations using the Unity engine for the purpose of measuring performance differences between the two. Both simulations do the same thing, but they each use different equations of motion in the software that runs in the background. I'm primarily using CPU performance as the main metric (in the amount of time taken between each frame of the player loop), so I have two very large arrays with various values for CPU speed that I would like to perform statistical analysis on.

That being said, I'm not entirely sure what test I should use. I considered using the Kruskal Wallis test, but I'm not a stats guy and I'm not sure whether this would be the most optimal test. It's my understanding that the K-W test is just a non-parametric ANOVA, which I think is what I need for my particular data sets, but I wanted to ask just to make sure.

Here's an example of what the arrays look like (the actual arrays contain some 300 values each):

```
model_1 = [8.364, 9.3808, 8.419, 8.8229, 8.4219, 8.7486, 8.9123]
model_2 = [286.218, 277.221, 284.443, 289.593, 292.626, 282.597, 290.929]
```

Comment: What are the shapes of these arrays, and what do the index sets representing? Are the two arrays of the same shape? For a given multi-index, does the entry in one array meaningfully pair with the entry in the other array?

Comment: @DifferentialCovariance Brett is using Unity, so he likely uses C# and in that case, an array has only one dimension: https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_arrays.php In R we would call that a vector.

Comment: @Bernhard I do not know much about Unity, so perhaps there is an implied context about it that I am unaware of. [C# supports multidimensional arrays](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays).

Comment: @DifferentialCovariance I do not know about C# and the link I posted mislead me. You are obviously right and I was wrong. Sorry for that.

Comment: @DifferentialCovariance I've updated my post to reflect the shape of the arrays. both models contain the same number of samples (around 300) where each value is the time from the previous frame. The values from one array are not meaningfully paired to those in another. I guess my biggest difficulty is trying to understand whether or not this data is normally distributed. Also, I'm not sure which test in general I should use to analyze this data in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a standard case for a simple t-test (i.e. asymptotic z-test) on the difference between the 2 average CPU speeds (times). The logic is as follows:

Let
$t_1 = [t_{1,1} \dots t_{1,n}]'$  and $t_2 = [t_{2,1} \dots t_{2,n}]'$ be the vectors of CPU time duration (or speed) for scenarios 1 and 2 respectively. We assume that both $t_{1,i}$ and $t_{2,i}$  come from the same distribution and are independently drawn, hence iid. Let $\bar t_1$ and $\bar t_2$ be the respective averages. By the Central Limit Theorem (CLT):

$$
\sqrt{n}(\bar t_1-\mu_1) \overset{d}{\to} \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2_1)
$$
for $\sigma^2_1$ being the variance of $t_{1,i}$. Analogously for $t_2$.

Now if indeed $t_1$ and $t_2$ were generated by the same distribution then the difference between the average should be zero, and the two averages have the same distribution, hence our null hypothesis is:
$$
H_0: \bar t_1 - \bar t_2 = \bar{\Delta t_{i}} = \Delta t =0.
$$

and $\mu_1=\mu_2=\mu$ and $\sigma_1^2=\sigma_2^2=\sigma^2$. By the CLT it holds that:

$$
\sqrt{n}(\Delta t) \overset{d}{\to} \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2_{\Delta})
$$

with $\sigma^2_{\Delta} = Var[t_{1,i} - t_{2,i}]=Var[t_{i,1}]+Var[t_{i,2}]=2\sigma^2$, due to independence.
Hence $H_0$ can be tested with a 2-sided test via the test statistic:
$$
t_{H_0}=\frac{\sqrt{n}\Delta t}{\sqrt{\hat \sigma^2_{\Delta}}}\overset{a}{\sim}\mathcal{N}(0,1)
$$
where $\sqrt{\hat \sigma^2_{\Delta}}$ is the sample standard deviation of the differences. (Note that there are may be a few other possible variations on this model, like choosing unequal sample sizes. Keyword: t-test.)

Comment: +1 ... This would establish that you have about the right significance level for a test of means as $n\to\infty$. What's missing is any assessment of whether the test would have relatively good power compared to some potential alternative test -- even assuming means is the quantity of interest; OP doesn't specify that. If $n$ were large because the effect of interest could be small, power would be a potential issue; correct type I error rate is not the only property we ask of our tests.

Comment: But isn't a simple t-test used on normalized data? I thought that this data would be considered non-parametric. I guess this is where I'm most confused. Also, why would it be a t-test as opposed to ANOVA?

Comment: @BrettMaverickMartin: What do you mean by normalized? The t test statistic is a normalization, in that it returns mean $0$ and variance $1$ under $H_0$. The data can't be parametric or non-parametric, only a model can. Here our parameters are $\sigma$, $\mu=0$, and the standard normal distribution. You can try other non-parametric tests, since e.g. they could have better power, as was pointed out. I think a t-test, i.e. comparing means, would suffice. The [t-test is a special case of ANOVA with 2 groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_analysis_of_variance), which is your case.

Comment: @PaulG I meant to say "normally distributed." My stats terminology is lacking. Also, this makes sense. So, why would I use a simple t-test as opposed to an unpaired 2-sided t-test? I should probably also mention that some of these arrays vary quite a bit depending on the number of objects that I've instantiated in the simulation. For instance, the mean delta time for model 2 is four times the mean of the first model in the case where I've instantiated over 10,000 "game objects." Does this make a difference in the test used?